# Construct an Injective and onto unbounded operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces, operator-theory, unbounded-operators

i was study functional analysis and i found a interesting problem. Let $X$ an infinite dimensional normed space. Construct an operator $T: X \rightarrow X$ such that $T$ is injective and onto.

Also, we can define a new norm on $X$ given by $\| x \|_{T} = \| T(x) \| $. Prove that $(X,\|  \cdot\|)$, $(X,\| \cdot \|_{T})$ are isometric.

My attemp:
I was trying to define the operator $T$ in the usual form of the books, take a Hamel Basis $(x_{i})_{i \in I}$,and WLOG suppose $\|x_{i}\|=1$ for any $i \in I$ then take countable subsequence $J = \{j_{1},j_{2},\dots\}$ of $I$. And define then as follows: $T(x_{ji}) = ix_{ji}$, and $T(x_{i})=0$ if $i \in I-J$. Then we can extend the function and we see that is unbouded. The problem is that, in this way $T$ is neither injective nor onto.

At this point i do not how to redefine the function to be bijective.
Any help is welcome, thanks!

Comment: I rewrote the answer to the generic form,  you were on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

This answer assumes A:  The axiom of choice, so all vector spaces have a Hamel basis and B:  You are working in a field of Characteristic 0.
EDIT:  As per @SeverinSchraven 's comment,  if working working in a field of characteristic $p$,  make the labels of $J$ from $\mathbb{N}\setminus p \mathbb{N}$ instead of $\mathbb{N}$

I decided to delete and restart to answer the generic question.  Setting things to 0 loses surjectivity,  instead take your countable subset $J$ of your index set $I$,  label the $J's$ in the natural way,  and define $$T(x_j)=jx_j,j\in  J$$,  $$T(x_i)=x_i\in I \setminus J$$
and extend via linearity.  This defines a linear, unbounded operator,  no matter the norm.

1-1 and onto are both done by looking at your elements as a finite linear combination of bases elements.   If $T(x_1)=T(x_2)$,  then $T(x_1 -x_2)=0$.   But by definition of $T$,  any basis elements in $x_1-x_2$ that come from $J$ would output $j\cdot$ the field element in that spot,  so that element is 0 (assuming our field is characteristic 0, anyways!)  Not even sure this is true if you have another field characteristic,  I haven't worked with vector spaces over such fields.

If the basis element of $x_1-x_2$ comes from $I\setminus J$,  then the coefficient of $T(x_1-x_2)$ will just be the underlying field element, so once again it must be 0.    Ergo it is injective.

For surjective,  take an arbitrary $x\in X$, it can be written as a linear combination of $x_i$ and $x_j$,   it has the obvious preimage, take $\frac 1 j x_j$ times the field element for any of those terms and just the field element for any $x_i$ terms

For isometry,  we need a linear map that makes it so the action of $T$ doesn't change the norms,  that's easy, just use $T^{-1}$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer i think that is the correct way! I Wrote something and i came to the same idea. Just one more question, i see that you prove that the operator T is one-to-one in the basis elements, so is that enough to see that T is one-to-one in all $X$?

Comment: @Pirry Yes, because a linear operator is uniquely defined by how it acts on basis elements

Comment: This is the classical result that says: A Linear Operator is One-To-One iff it sends LI sets on Li Sets, or i'm wrong? Anyway, thanks for your answer, it's a very elegant solution to this problem!

Comment: If you wish to do this in characteristic $p$, then you need to ensure that the factors are not divisible by $p$. Thus, you want to enummerate your countable set by $\mathbb{N}\setminus p \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Obvious in retrospect, thanks! I edited it into the main answer, with attribution

Comment: @Alan That is the mean thing about math. It always seems as if it was obvious/trivial. As an undergraduate that bothered me a lot (now a bit less) :)